# Looking for Magento 2 API Postman collection

Tags: magento2, api

I am looking for the most complete postman collection for the Magento 2 API. I generated a schema with Swagger and imported it as described [in this article](https://medium.com/@yvoronoy/how-to-generate-schema-for-magento2-api-and-import-to-postman-c08a0318af98). But it is missing the titles, so it's hard to find and navigate endpoints.

I am looking for a recent version for Magento Open Source. It would be great if the endpoints are grouped logically just like in swagger.

Comment: Found This online, Hope it helps you out. https://www.postman.com/red-water-magento-rest-api/workspace/red-water-6485-s-public-workspace/collection/8094635-4fb1f5a8-ab91-407c-b259-4e3344d9b785?ctx=documentation

Comment: This too maybe more up to date https://www.postman.com/api-evangelist/workspace/magento/overview